# Don't understand string formatting expressions

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am havig some doubt regarding the string formatting expressions in python:

The general syntax of the string formatting expression is

```
%[keyname][flags][width][.precision]typecode
```

I am having couple of doubt in this and these are:

1. What does keyname stands for?
2. Can we use keyword arguments instead of variable name and dictionary?

For example:

```
x="%(z)d is equal to" %{"z":1}  # This expression gives me the required output.
```

but when I try this one:

```
x="%(z)d is equal to" %("z"=1)  # Causes error. I am getting confused with this.
```

similarly when I use like this:

```
x="%(z)d is equal to" %dict("z"=1)
```

It also shows an error. Why?

Comment: The correct way to pass keyword arguments is `dict(z=1)`, not `dict('z'=1)`.  The string formatting operator requires a mapping as the right hand argument, so there's no way to make your second example work.

Answer (score 1):

*Keyname* means the name in parentheses, for example `z` in `%(z)d`. It is called *keyname* because `"z"` is the dictionary key that will return the value you want substituted in your string, in this case `1`.

You are confusing two ways to specify a dictionary.

One is with braces `{ }`, for which the syntax is `{"z": 1}`. You can specify the key (here `z`) as a constant or as a variable and the variable can contain any hashable value: tuples qualify, lists don't, recursively.

So, as you have found out, this is valid:

```
x = "%(z)d is equal to" % {"z":1}
```

The other way is to call the `dict` constructor, for which the syntax is `dict(z=1)`. But here the key must be *a valid Python identifier* because in this syntax you are passing `z` as a keyword parameter to `dict()`.

In this syntax the equivalent of the first valid example is:

```
x ="%(z)d is equal to" % dict(z=1)
```

You are getting errors on the other lines because

- `("z"=1)` does not specify a `dict` because it has neither `{...}` nor a `dict()` constructor call.
- `dict("z"=1)` is mixing up the first syntax (key is a constant, use `{ }` and colon instead) with the second syntax (key can't be a constant: it needs to be an *identifier* that you provide as a keyword parameter to the `dict()` call).